# TypeError: ‘undefined’ is not an object (evaluating)

Tags: html, reactjs, react-native, performance

I'm started react-native tutorial on youtube, and I get error this one.

```
 TypeError: ‘undefined’ is not an object
```

This is File it is showing from:

```
<Touchable>
           <Image
             source={require(‘../assets/badalboupic.jpg)} />
   

           <Text >
           TafTun AutoMechanics
               <Text />
         </Touchable>
```

Please help. Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Occurs in Safari: when you read a property or call a method on an undefined object .Initialize state with reasonable default values in the constructor. –

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this :

```
   <TouchableWithoutFeedback>
     <>
       <Image source={require('../assets/badalboupic.jpg')} />
       <Text >TafTun AutoMechanics</Text>
     </>
   </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

1. You missed a quote in your `Image` source
2. In react native,forward slashes are placed before words in closing tags,not after
3. You have to choose between a `TouchableWithoutFeedback`,`TouchableOpacity`, `TouchableHighlight` or a `Pressable` element.